# Best way to share functionality but have different styles?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, styled-components

I am building a Next.js website and I am running into this issue:

I have 3 forms which work essentially the same way but they all look different. I would like to build the actual form only once but be able to somehow style it in different ways without duplicating too much code and doing things the "right way".

The solution I have come up with is to simply give the form a class and style its children via classic CSS. This works but feels "wrong" considering the rest of the project is using Styled-components. I would like to find a solution that follows the principles behind SC instead of adding global styles to the app.

This is what the code currently looks like:

```js
// form.js
export default Form = () => {
  /* ... hooks and stuff ... */  

  return (
    <form>
      /* ... */
    </form>
  )
}

// styled-form-1.js
import Form from './Form.js'

export default Form = () => {
  return (
    <Form className="styled-1" />
  )
}
```

```css
// globalStyles.css
.styled-1 form { /* ... */ }
.styled-1 input { /* ... */ }
.styled-1 button { /* ... */ }

.styled-2 form { /* ... */ }
.styled-2 input { /* ... */ }
.styled-2 button { /* ... */ }
```

As I said... This works fine but I want to do it the styled-components way. I just cannot find that solution.

Comment: Try styled-components' [theming](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming) feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass function to styled-component's template literal to adapt it based on props. For example:

```
const Button = styled.button`
  background: ${props => props.primary ? "red" : "blue"};
  color: ${props => props.primary ? "blue" : "red"};

  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
`;

render(
  <div>
    <Button>Normal</Button>
    <Button primary>Primary</Button>
  </div>
);
```

By this way you can create single styled-components for your form and change it's styles based on the props. For more, check official [Doc](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props)

Comment: Would you still do this if the styles where wildly different? I'm talking color, size, position, etc.

Comment: If you have large number of variable styles, then you can go for [theming](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming) approach otherwise the props based approach. With themes you can create three different themes for your three forms and just simply pass those themes to your respective styled-component @Ackman